# Storing time and program output into separate variables

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

With bash, how do I store the time it takes for my program to execute in one variable, and the output of my program in another variable? I know that `time` sends its output to `stdout`; the closest I've got is this:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
time_output=$( { time echo hello world 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1 )
```

but "hello world" is printed to the terminal. How to I capture "hello world" to another variable?

I've also tried:

```
prog_output=$(time_output=$( { time echo hello world 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1 ) )
```

but this doesn't work. `prog_output` contains nothing and "hello world" is printed to the terminal.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing the output of bash time in script variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868811/capturing-the-output-of-bash-time-in-script-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
prog_output=`( time ls ) 2> time_output`
time_output=`cat time_output`
```