# Capturing the output of bash time in script variable

Tags: bash, shell, time, wget

I'm trying this:

```
TIMEFORMAT=%R;
foo=$(time wget http://www.mysite.com)
echo $foo
```

and when I execute I see the number I want in the output but not in variable foo (echo $foo print nothing).

Why is that?

Comment: This is a FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are not capturing anything in `foo` because `time` sends its output on `stderr`. The trouble is that the `wget` command also sends most of its output on `stderr`. To split the two streams (and throw away the output from `wget`) you will need to use a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html):

```sh
TIMEFORMAT=%R;
foo=$( time ( wget http://www.example.com 2>/dev/null 1>&2 ) 2>&1 )
echo $foo
```

Here is an explanation of what's going on...

The inner part of this command:

```sh
( wget http://www.example.com 2>/dev/null 1>&2 )
```

Sends both `stderr` and `stdout` to `/dev/null`, essentially throwing them away.

The outer part:

```sh
foo=$( time ( ... ) 2>&1 )
```

Sends `stderr` from the `time` command to the same place that `stdout` is sent so that it may be captured by the [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) (`$()`).

**Update:**

If you wanted to get really clever, you can have the output of `wget` passed through to `stderr` by juggling the file descriptors like this:

```sh
foo=$( time ( wget http://www.example.com 2>&1 ) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 )
```

Comment: You, @lee-netherton, are a saviour!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the following to capture the output of `time`:

```
~$ var=$({ TIMEFORMAT=%R; time sleep 1; } 2>&1)
~$ echo $var
1.001
```